# "where" keyword in class declaration in c sharp

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Could anyone help me with the line `where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()` in the following class declaration.

```
public abstract class BaseEntityManager<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
```

Comment: I think he's asking for an explanation of the syntax.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`where TEntity : ...` applies constraints to the generic parameter TEntity. In this case, the constraints are:

class:   The argument to TEntity must be a reference type
IEntity: The argument must be or implement the IEntity interface
new():   The argument must have a public parameterless constructor

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: If you could add some code showing how somebody might use BaseEntityManager as a base class that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 6):

The `where` keyword after the class declaration restrict what type the generic `TEntity` could be. In this case `TEntity` *must* be a class (meaning it can't be a value type like `int` or `DateTime`), and it *must* implement the interface `IEntity`. The `new()` constraint indicates that methods inside this class have the ability to call the default constructor of the generic class represented by `TEntity` (e.g. `new TEntity()`)

Answer (score 0):

Where is a generic type constraint. That lines reads that the type TEntity must be a reference type as opposed to a value type, must implement the interface IEntity and it must have a constructor that takes no parameters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Answer (score -1):

What's the question ?

Let me take at shot at what i think the question is. The constraint ensures that you can only subclass BaseEntityManager with a generic parameter which is a reference type implementing IEntity and containing a parameterless constructor.

E.X.

```
public class Product : IEntity {
  public Product() {}
}

public class Wrong {
  public Wrong() {}
}

public class WrongAgain : IEntity {
   private Wrong() {}
}


// compiles
public ProductManager : BaseEntityManager<Product> {}


// Error - not implementing IEntity
public WrongManager : BaseEntityManager<Wrong> {}


/ Error - no public parameterless constructor
public WrongAgainManager : BaseEntityManager<WrongAgain> {}
```

see [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: "Could anyone help me with the line...?" that's the question. It's obvious what he's asking.